# Error with browsersync with scss recompilation

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

As I got errors on compilation for scss files, I added browsersync to my prject and seem to fix recompilation issue when modifying scss file which use variables from another one, but now I get

```
TypeError: args.cb is not a function
```

when I recompile css file after modifying scss file twice or more..this is my config:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', ['sasscompil'], function() {
    browserSync.init({
        //changer l'adresse du site pour lequel utiliser browserSync
        proxy: "http://xxx.vmdev"
    });
});
```

how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

BrowserSync reload need to be the last task done by gulp,so we need to put the BS task at the end of the process like this:

```
gulp.task('default', ['watch','browser-sync']);
```

and removing reference to the sass compile task liek this:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {..
```